# serverless - aws - SecureLambdaFunction env

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I'm having the following case:

I setting several environments variables on my serverless.yml file like:

```
ONE_CLIENT_SECRET=${ssm:/one/key_one~true}
ONE_CLIENT_PUBLIC=${ssm:/one/key_two~true}

ANOTHER_SERVICE_KEY=${ssm:/two/key_one~true}
ANOTHER_SERVICE_SECRET=${ssm:/two/key_two~true}
```

let' say I have like 10 envs, when I try to deploy I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: SecureLambdaFunction - Lambda was unable to configure your environment variables because the environment variables you have provided exceeded the 4KB limit. String measured: JSON_WITH_MY_VARIABLES_HERE
```

So I cannot deploy, I have an idea of what the problem is but I dont have a clear path to solve it, so my questions are:

1) How can I extend the 4Kb limit? 
2) assuming my variables are set using SSM, I'm using the EC2 Parameter store to save them. (this is more related to a serverless team or someone that knows the topic) how does it work behind the scenes?
   - when I run `sls deploy` does it fetch for the values and included on the .zip file? (this is what I think it does, I just want to clarify) or does it fetch the values when I exec the lambdas? I'm asking cause I go to the aws lambda console and I can see em set there.

Thanks!

Comment: Warning: Possibly dumb comment - could you possibly daisy-chain lambda calls?

Comment: what do you mean? I cannot even compile the project cause the size of the environment variables. that is basically the problem, not the executions

Comment: Told you it was possibly dumb. Just toes into lambdas right now...and assumed you could get your needed values from external sources. Please excuse my newb-ness.

Comment: :D! not dumb at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look around in deep, I came with the following conclusion:

Using this pattern `ONE_CLIENT_SECRET=${ssm:/one/key_one~true}` means that the sls framework is going to download the values on compilation time and embed into the project, this is where the problem comes, you can see this after uploading the project, your variables are going to be set on plain text on the lambda console.

My solution was to use a middy middleware to load ssm values when executing the lambda. This means, you need to code your project in a way that does not trigger any code until the variables are available and find a good strategy to catch the variables (cold start), otherwise, it will add more time to the execution.

The limit of 4Kb cannot be changed and after read about this, it seems obvious.

So short story, find a strategy of middleware and embed values that work best for you if you find this problem.

Comment: I would like to share an alternative way to load SSM values to lambda environment by using Laconia. The framework encourages the use of environment variable, similar to sls framework, but the value will not be retrieved on compilation time. You can find more information here: https://laconiajs.io/docs/guides/retrieving-secrets (Disclaimer: I'm the author)